# Multiple value in a column sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I'm working on an SSIS package. This package loads information from a form a verdure files. the package works perfectly, however my issue is in one of the column called 'SpecialUnit'.

On the form the customer can select 23 values and all this values get recorded as a comma separated. In my SSIS I have created different fields for all 23 values I wanted all this values to show 1 when the person selects them.
Example.

```sql
CASE WHEN sp.CodeText = 'Transit Dept.'
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
END AS FollowUpByTransit,
```

I have a table that separates the comma delimiter, but when loading I do not have a value I want which is 1 or 0.

Comment: Your question is a bit short on sample data and results. You can use `',' + 'Foo,Bar,Fizz,Buzz' + ',' like '%,Foo,%'` to determine if `'Foo'` is in a comma-delimited list, e.g. `'Foo,Bar,Fizz,Buzz'`. Not a great solution, but a useful technique. It can be used in your `case` expression to generate a `0`/`1` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make your 23 fields as calculated fields, then on the equation for each field you can use something like the below

```
As case when CodeText like '%Transit Dept%' then 1 else 0 end as FollowUpByTransit
```

So you would need to use the like operator, so you ignore the commas and other values.

If your code words may be a bit similar to each other, you can go with the idea HABO presented and thats somthing like the below

```
   As case when (','+CodeText+',') like '%,Transit Dept,%' then 1 else 0 end as FollowUpByTransit
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Ali and HABO.  The like operation was what I was looking for. It was fixed.